# Remember state on refreshing - jQuery with cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, cookies

I am trying to develop a script that would remember the state after page refresh.

Here is what I've done so far.

jQuery:

```
      $(window).ready(function() {
var voteId = $('.gallery-item a');
$(voteId).click(function() {
$(this).text('Thank you!');
$(this).css('background-color', 'green');
});
});
```

I have tried this, but didn't have luck with it:

jQuery:

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for(var i=0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    var equals = cookies[i].indexOf("=");
    var name = equals > -1 ? cookies[i].substr(0, equals) : cookies[i];
    document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
```

Comment: @Darren Willows answer should the trick for you. However, If cookie is not the only way you want to go, you can try localstorage or sessionStorage as well, it can serve your purpose.

Comment: I know about localStorage and sessionStorage, but never used them.

Answer (score 3):

**Set a Cookie**

The parameters of the function below are the name of the **cookie (cname)**, the **value of the cookie (cvalue)**, and the number of days until the cookie should **expire (exdays)**.

The function sets a cookie by adding together the cookiename, the cookie value, and the expires string.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

**Get a Cookie**

Take the cookiename as parameter **(cname)**.

Create a variable **(name)** with the text to search for **(cname + "=")**.

Split document.cookie on semicolons into an array called ca (ca = document.cookie.split(';')).

Loop through the ca array (i=0;i

If the cookie is found **(c.indexOf(name) == 0)**, return the value of the cookie **(c.substring(name.length,c.length)**.

If the cookie is not found, return "".

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

**Set and Get**

```
setCookie("message", "Thank You", 365); 
setCookie("color", "#0F0", 365); 

var message=getCookie("message"); 
var color=getCookie("color");
```

This will set two cookies **message** and **color** with an exp of 1 Year.
You could do it all in one with a JSON Array as well.

Comment: Sorry, could elaborate more? Where exactly do I place this?

Comment: You put it in a JS file or in your Script tags and then call the functions when you need it.

Comment: Please see my question above. The jQuery is changing from the previous state to "Thank you" state. I would need that to be remembered by cookies so when I refresh the page the "Thank you" remains. This is a voting system I'm working on, and when user votes the "Thank you" appears. I need that to remain after refresh as well.

Could you place your code in jsfiddle please? I'm not very experienced with JS.

Comment: I do not know what more I can do, this method above is a JavaScript only method. It also will remember the cookie on refresh, I can not do all of your work for you. Clearly you should not be doing JavaScript yet as you do not know enough at present to be able to do this yourself.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, only it doesn't help me. I already have cookies set. What I want it is to remember the change from "Vote" to "Thank you", which happens when 'click' is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JS Cookie as it does not require jQuery.

A simple, lightweight JavaScript API for handling cookies

Works in all browsers

Accepts any character

Heavily tested

No dependency

Unobtrusive JSON support

Supports AMD/CommonJS

RFC 6265 compliant

Enable custom decoding

Very good Wiki

~800 bytes gzipped!

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

```
Cookies.set('name', 'true', { expires: 7, path: '' });
Cookies.get('name'); // => 'true'
Cookies.remove('name', { path: '' });
```

Comment: Thanks, but no sorry. I would like to get this done with jQuery, or simply JavaScript.

Comment: Just a side note here, this is a JS only solution. JS stands for JavaScript. I also hope you know that Simply JavaScript is a book and not a form of JavaScript.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but I wouldn't use any plugins. What I need it the script that remembers the "Thank you" + background color: green state.

If you could elaborate the upper answer, I would be more than grateful. 
Thanks.